# TCP Payload vs Cellular Data Usage

Tags: tcp

I have a device that connects to the AWS via a LTE CAT1 modem. In the effort to reduce cellular data consumption, I put some monitoring code to keep track the amount of data usage at the TCP layer. This number comes out about 30KB per day. Does anyone know if there is a way to estimate how much cellular data this number gets translated to?

Comment: You need to know how many packets there are to get an accurate answer.  But I imagine any "overhead" will not change the price significantly.